# RenderMan incident vector inconsistencies

Tags: graphics, 3d, render, renderman

I am working on translating a series of light and surface shaders from 3Delight to PRMan, and I have discovered a difference between the two that I cannot work out. It seems that when a surface shader is being evaluated for transmission opacity due to a trace in a light shader, the incident vector `I` in PRMan is being set to the surface's normal.

In my example scene, there is a hemisphere floating above a disc. A distant light from above is projecting traced transmission values onto the surfaces behind them (a little backwards for a light, but this is a demo). The surface on the hemisphere is rendering as a solid coloured by its normals when viewed by the camera, but with the opacity of the incident direction when queried for transmission.

This is what I expect it to look like, and what I receive from 3Delight:

[image: 3Delight Render]

Note that the floor is solid nearly pure green; the colour we would expect if the incident angle is vertical. However, this is what I receive when I render the exact same scene with PRMan:

[image]

It appears to be projecting the normals.

I have attempted fetching values via `rayinfo` and calculating a new `I`, but those values all match with what `I` is actually set to. I have also noticed discrepancies with `E`, but I have not been able to nail down what it is being set to in PRMan.

**Q: How can I get the incident vector `I that I am expecting?**

Contents of `scene.rib`:

```
Display "falloff.tiff" "framebuffer" "rgba"
Projection "perspective" "fov" [17]
Format 400 400 1
ShadingRate 0.25
PixelSamples 3 3

# Move the camera
Translate 0 -0.65 10
Rotate 30 -1 0 0

Option "searchpath" "string shader" ".:&"

WorldBegin

    LightSource "projector" "projector_light"
        "point to" [0 -1 0]

    Surface "matte"
    TransformBegin
        Rotate 90 1 0 0
        Disk 0 1.25 360
    TransformEnd

    Surface "inspect_incident"
    Attribute "visibility" "integer transmission" [1]
    Attribute "shade" "string transmissionhitmode" "shader"
    TransformBegin
        Translate 0 1 0
        Rotate -90 1 0 0 
        Sphere 1 0 1 360
    TransformEnd

WorldEnd
```

Contents of `projector.sl`:

```
light projector(

    float intensity = 1;
    color lightcolor = 1;

    point from = point "shader" (0,0,0);
    point to = point "shader" (0,0,1);
    float maxdist = 1e12;

) {

    uniform vector dir = normalize(to - from);
    solar(dir, 0.0) {
        Cl = intensity * lightcolor * (1 - transmission(Ps, Ps - dir * maxdist));
    }

}
```

Contents of `inspect_incident.sl`:

```
class inspect_incident() {

    public void opacity(output color Oi) {
        vector In = normalize(I);
        Oi = color((In + 1) / 2);
    }

    public void surface(output color Ci, Oi) {
        vector Nn = normalize(N);
        Ci = color((Nn + 1) / 2);
        Oi = 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the documentation for the special `__computesOpacity` parameter of surface shaders:

> A value of 0 means that the shader does not compute opacity (i.e Oi == Os). This can be used to override
>   a transmission hit mode of shader. For such shaders, the opacity()
>   method will be skipped for transmission rays.
>
> A value of 1 means that the shader does indeed compute opacity. Such
>   shaders will be run to evaluate their opacity for transmission rays.
>   That result may be cached by the renderer, and thus must be
>   view-independent.
>
> A value of 2 means that the shader computes opacity in view-dependent
>   manner. As such the renderer will avoid caching opacity for
>   transmission rays. The opacity is still cached for the purpose of
>   controlling continuations on diffuse and specular rays, but
>   view-dependent shadows may be generated using areashadow() or
>   transmission(). For mode 2, the opacity() method must only depend on
>   view-dependent entities within a check for raytype == "transmission"..

And quoting Brian from Pixar:

> Set it to `2` to do what you want. What you're seeing is the render runs
>   `opacity` once with the domes' `I`, and caches that.